# I have problem with editing fetched values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split, trim, innertext

When I extract data and want to add them to table, the given JavaScript code only retrieves the first row from each `<td>` and ignores the rest. This is a problem because I don't know how to make it retrieve all rows for the second, third, and fourth `<td>` and add them as new thing separatly when they start with "-" sign. In first `<td>` i need only "Title 1". I would greatly appreciate your help.

JavaScript:

```
const dataSets = [{ set: new Set(), columnIndex: 0 }, { set: new Set(), columnIndex: 1 }, { set: new Set(), columnIndex: 2 }, { set: new Set(), columnIndex: 3 }];
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
const rows = tbody.querySelectorAll("tr");


for (let row of rows) {
    const cells = row.querySelectorAll("td");
    for (let dataSet of dataSets) {
        const cell = cells[dataSet.columnIndex];
        if (cell) {
            dataSet.set.add(cell.innerText.trim().split('\n')[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
        <tr>
          <td>Title 1<br />
          Line title 1
          </td>
          <td>Specific 1</td>
          <td>- Thing 1<br />
          - Thing 2
          </td>
          <td>- Something 1<br />
          - Something 2<br />
          - Something 3<br />
          - Something 4<br />
          - Something 5<br />
          - Something 6<br />
          - Something 7
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You are splitting the text at the newline, and then you are accessing only the first item of the resulting array - so not sure how you'd expect any other result here? Or what exactly you even want to _achieve_ in the first place.

Comment: If you want to process each "line" of these texts separately - well then _loop over_ the result of the `split` call?

Comment: @CBroe I know that if(cell{...} is wrong, this is good for first <td> because it's adding to dataSets only Title1, same in case of second <td>. But in third and fourth <td> i need to add every text with "-" but separately. So in dataSets[3] will be ["- Something 1", "- Something 2" ...]. Same but different things in dataSets[2]. I'm not that smart to find an idea how to do that and how to separate them by "-" or by "<br>"

Comment: The computer can't _guess_, that you only want the first line from the first cell, but all lines from some other cell. So you'll need to find some way to _specify_ that within your logic first of all.